# Hide UIView when UICollectionView scrolls down

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a project which has a NavigationController, TabBarController and CollectionView to show content. Above this CollectionView is a small dashboard which shows relevant information to the logged in user. This is all set up and works correctly. Take a look at this illustration to get the idea:

[image: Project Setup]

What I want now, is that when the user scrolls down the CollectionView, the dashboard disappears and thus scrolls with the CollectionView. I have thought about a few different options:

- Add a ScrollView fitting the entire contentSize (starting beneath the NavigationController and ending above the TabBarController). Problem with this is that I have read it is not best practice to add a CollectionView to a ScrollView, because they will continuously interfere with each other.
- Change the frame (y position) of the dashboard (UIView) in ScrollViewDidScroll
- Add the dashboard (UIView) as a header to the CollectionView

I am merely wondering what the best approach would be and how this would work exactly. I currently have a TabBarController which loads in the HomeViewController, in there I set up the Dashboard and underneath is another UIView (contentView) which is the container for the CollectionView.

Can anybody point me in the right direction on how to implement this and what the best scenario would be? Or an open-source project which uses a similar technique that could give me the necessary inspiration? I am writing in Swift 4.2.

Comment: #3 is the most promising, and halfway reading your question, first thing pops in my mind was #3

Comment: I have never worked with headers in a CollectionView (or TableView, for that matter) before. Are there any issues I should know about? I will only be using one section to show an entire list of posts underneath (a feed), so the reusability for different sections doesn't concern me. Anything else I should look out for?

Comment: First thing is first, look out custom header view in collection view tuts.